# unix cp files from subfolders with pattern to new destination keeping subfolders

Tags: unix, cp, subdirectory

In unix.
How can I copy files with a certain pattern ('pattern') to a new location keeping the subfolder structure:

```
/from/dir1name/a.pattern.b
/from/dir1name/c.pattern.d
/from/dir2name/e.pattern.f
/from/dir2name/g.pattern.h
```

Should be copied to :

```
 /to/dir1name/a.pattern.b
 /to/dir1name/c.pattern.d
 /to/dir2name/e.pattern.f
 /to/dir2name/g.pattern.h
```

Something along this will not keep the subfolder structure:

```
cp /from/*dir/*pattern* /to/
```

Do I need a loop to grasp the dir names (psuodocode):

```
for d in from/dir*; do cp "from/$d/*pattern*" "to/$d/"; done
```

This must have been asked before but I failed to find it on SO.

Comment: Take a look at the `find` utility along with its `exec` feature.

Comment: I am aware of this thanks - but I still can not conserve folder structure. E.g. find /from/*dir/ -type f -iregex "*pattern*" -exec cp {} /to/ \

Answer (score 1):

GNU cp has a `--parents` option that may be useful. `cd /from ; cp --parents dir*/*pattern* /to/`

You need to `cd` first so the part of the path you *don't* want replicated does not appear in the source arguments to cp.

There's no equivalent in traditional unix cp; you'll have to write your own loop and include `mkdir` commands for the intermediate levels, or cheat and use `tar`:

```
(cd /from ; tar cf - dir*/*pattern*) | (cd /to ; tar xvf -)
```